# A way to run XQuery from R

Tags: r, xml, xquery

I know xml2 package in R can run XPath queries on XML documents. I am wondering if there is a way (a package) to run queries in the [XQuery](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) language from R.

Comment: There is an R client for BaseX https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/tree/master/basex-api/src/main/r

Comment: My RbaseX client is fully compliant with the server protocol and can be downloaded from CRAN